# Webpack, React hot reloader and multiple entries

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server

All the examples I've seen have the entries as an array of strings when doing hot module replacement.

How does it work when you have multiple entries? I tried the following and still got the `Uncaught exception: HMR is disabled` message.

Webpack config:

```
module.exports = {
    context: path.join(staticPath, "js"),
    entry: {
        hot: 'webpack/hot/only-dev-server',
        main: './main.js',
        admin: './admin.js',
        vendor: './vendor.js',
        devServerClient: 'webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:4000'
    },

    output: {
        filename: "[name].bundle.js",
        path: path.join(staticPath, "js/"),
        publicPath: "http://localhost:4000/static/bundles/"
    },

    module: {
        loaders: [
            { test: /\.js$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loaders: ["react-hot", "babel-loader"] },
            { test: /\.json$/, loader: "json" }
        ]
    },

    resolve: {
        extensions: ['', '.js', '.json']
    },

    plugins: [
        new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin('shared', 'shared.bundle.js'),
        new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
        new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin(),
        new BundleTracker({ path: rootPath, filename: './webpack-stats.json' })
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
var publicPath = 'http://localhost:4000';

module.exports = {
    context: path.join(staticPath, "js"),
    entry: {
        entry1: [
            'webpack-dev-server/client?' + publicPath,
            'webpack/hot/only-dev-server',
            './index.js'
        ],
        entry2: [
            'webpack-dev-server/client?' + publicPath,
            'webpack/hot/only-dev-server',
            './index2.js'
        ],
        /* etc */
    },
    output: {
        filename: "[name].bundle.js",
        path: path.join(staticPath, "js/"),
        publicPath: publicPath + "/static/bundles/"
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                loaders: ['react-hot', 'babel-loader'],
            },
            /* other loaders */
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
        /* other plugins */
    ],

    /* these are command line options */
    devServer: {
        port: 4000,
        hot: true
    }
};
```

I took the webpack config I use for hot loading and mixed in parts of your config. The biggest difference is how the entry file object is structured. I struggled with getting this to work as well for multiple entry files, I got it to work mostly through trial and error.

Comment: Is there any way to get this working without multiple reload calls if you are using multiple-entries where 1 or more of the entries may be present on the same page?.  For example a Common.js / Vendor.js + a page/app specific Foo.js  - wanting all entries to hot reload.